# Unresolved external symbol even if everything seems OK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

I'm not used to coding on Windows, and I am puzzled with this error on VS.

I am developping a static library `libA`, another one `libB` calling some methods in `libA`, and a program `prog` calling some methods in `libB`.

`libA` compiles without any problems.

Same for `libB`. The include and lib folders about `libA` are given to VS, as well as `libA.lib` as an additional dependency.

For `prog`, I give the include and lib folders concerning both `libA` and `libB`. The two libaries themselves are given as additional dependencies. It compiles, but while linking, I got a couple of errors LNK2001 of the type:

`unresolved external symbol "public virtual void __thiscall libA::classA1::methodA1(void)" (?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAXXZ) in File libB.lib(classB1.obj)`

I did a dumpbin of `libB` and the symbol `?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAXXZ` appears many times in the dump file.

```
Dump of file .\libB.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

Archive member name at 8: /                
61C9303F time/date Mon Dec 27 12:17:19 2021
         uid
         gid
       0 mode   36987E size correct header end

14630 public symbols 

...
3F43C3C ?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAXXZ
...

Archive member name at 3698C2: /                
61C9303F time/date Mon Dec 27 12:17:19 2021
         uid
         gid
       0 mode   36272A size correct header end

61 offsets

...
32 ?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAXXZ
... 

SECTION HEADER #42 .text$mn name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
     1D7 size of raw data
    5FA3 file pointer to raw data (00005FA3 to 00006179)
    617A file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       D number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers 60501020 flags
         Code
         COMDAT; sym= "public: virtual void __cdecl libA::classA1::methodA1(void)" (?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ)
         16 byte align
         Execute Read

...

SECTION HEADER #92
  .xdata name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
      1C size of raw data
    6B4E file pointer to raw data (00006B4E to 00006B69)
    6B6A file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       1 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40301040 flags
         Initialized Data
         COMDAT; sym= $unwind$?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ
         4 byte align
         Read Only

...

SECTION HEADER #93
  .pdata name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
       C size of raw data
    6B74 file pointer to raw data (00006B74 to 00006B7F)
    6B80 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       3 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40301040 flags
         Initialized Data
         COMDAT; sym= $pdata$?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ
         4 byte align
         Read Only

...

RELOCATIONS #93
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000000  ADDR32NB                   00000000       124  $LN269
 00000004  ADDR32NB                   000001D7       124  $LN269
 00000008  ADDR32NB                   00000000       22A  $unwind$?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ

...

RELOCATIONS #101
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000000  ADDR64            00000000 00000000       3BA  ??_R4classA1@libA@@6B@ (const libA::classA1::`RTTI Complete Object Locator')
 00000008  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        D3  ??_EclassA1@libA@@UEAAPEAXI@Z (public: virtual void * __cdecl libA::classA1::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int))
 00000010  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        8D  _purecall
 00000018  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        8D  _purecall
 00000020  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        CE  ?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ (public: virtual void __cdecl libA::classA1::methodA1(void))
 00000028  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        CF  ?methodA2@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ (public: virtual void __cdecl libA::classA1::methodA2(void))

...

0CE 00000000 SECT42 notype ()    External     | ?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ (public: virtual void __cdecl libA::classA1::methodA1(void))

...

22A 00000000 SECT92 notype       Static       | $unwind$?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ
22B 00000000 SECT93 notype       Static       | .pdata
    Section length    C, #relocs    3, #linenums    0, checksum AAAF74B1, selection    5 (pick associative Section 0x42)
22D 00000000 SECT93 notype       Static       | $pdata$?methodA1@classA1@libA@@UEAAXXZ
22E 00000000 SECT94 notype       Static       | .voltbl
    Section length    4, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum D5442740, selection    5 (pick associative Section 0x42)
```

Same for the dumplib file of `libA`.

If it helps, here is the linker command for `prog`:

`/OUT:"C:\prog\Release\prog.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\prog\Release\prog.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "libA.lib" "libB.lib" "some_other_libs.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\prog\Release\prog.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\prog.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"Release\prog.iobj" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"Release\prog.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1`

Comment: Apparently, `libA::classA1::methodA1` is not actually implemented in either library.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it is true that some methods from `libA` are pure virtual methods, but they are implemented in `libB` (`libA` is actually a framework). Moreover, I also have this error with non-pure virtual methods from `libA`, with an implementation by default in `libA`.

Comment: Try switching the order of libA.lib and libB.lib in the command line.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I wasn't convinced that would solve the problem. I swapped their order just in case, and it didn't change the problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: "Appears many time". I'll suggest to post them here as well. For both libA and libB.

Comment: @LouisGo I just added extracts from the libB's dumpbin file where the symbol for methodA1 is mentionned. the dumpbin file for libA is quite similar.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Have you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-170)?And try to use `#pragma comment(lib, "XXX.lib")`

Comment: Pure virtual or not, `libA::classA1::methodA1` is apparently being called (somewhere in `classB1`), and so needs to be implemented; or else avoid calling it. Fun fact - pure virtual methods can in fact have implementation, and can be called. I suspect you have a situation similar to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7T1haq9KK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem.

libA and libB were correctly working on Linux, so I didn't understand why I got this problem on Windows.

Turns out that, I don't really know why, but the VS solution file generated by CMake allowed to compile libA with an x86 target architecture, but together with the additional option "/machine x64" in the command line section (Project Properties > Linker (or Librarian for a static library) > Command Line).

I removed this "/machine x64" option, recompiled libA, and now the whole thing compiles and links.